# Uncheck radio button on click using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, unchecked

Radio buttons are unchecked only at page refresh

```
<input type="radio" name="test">
    1<input type="radio" name="test">2
   <input type="button" id="btn" />

$("#btn").click(function(){

$(':radio').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
    })

});
```

I have created a **fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/220/

**But its not working with Bootstrap**

Answer (score 17):

Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr`:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
```

[[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/221/)]

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
 $(this).prop('checked', false);
 //$('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked', false);
```

You can see this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)** for differentiate between `.prop()` with `.attr()`. `.attr()` suitable for accessing HTML element attributes like`(name, id, class,etc..)` and `.prop()` for DOM element properties that returned boolean value for most case.

From **[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** official page :

> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

Answer (score 3):

using .prop() inbuild function.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy use following will help you:

```
$("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Check your updated [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/224/)

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery > 1.5, you should use `prop` instead of `attr`.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jKJc/225/).

See [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`.prop` only sets properties, not attributes.

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Or you can use `is` to do this

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $(this).prop('checked',false);
   }
});
});
```

Comment: can you please create a JSFiddle for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a radio button when it's unchecked and uncheck it when it's checked, there's a catch. As soon as you click on the input, the value is set to true, so the expected behaviour cannot be achieved. So first you have to block the action of the click, then use the "mousedown" and "mouseup" events to stealthily detect the state of the input. Idem for label

https://jsfiddle.net/greatalf/k7cwfemp/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uncheck radio button</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="radio" name="options" value="option1" id="option1">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label><br>

    <input type="radio" name="options" value="option2" id="option2">
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label><br>

    <input type="radio" name="options" value="option3" id="option3">
    <label for="option3">Option 3</label><br>
    
</body>
</html>
```

```
    $('label').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        var inputId = '#' + $(this).attr("for");
        if( $(inputId).prop("checked") === true )
        {
            $(inputId).prop("checked", false);
        }
        else {
            $(inputId).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
    
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    })
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    
        if( $(this).prop("checked") === true )
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
        else {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    
        if( $(this).prop("checked") === false )
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
```